# Squareful values of polynomials

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory

Recall that an integer $n$ is called *squareful* if for every prime $p$ with $p \mid n$, we also have $p^2 \mid n$.

Any squareful number can be written uniquely as $n= x^2 y^3$ where $y$ is squarefree. From this, it is easy to see that
$$\#\{ n \in \mathbb{Z}: |n| \leq X, \, n \text{ is squareful} \} \ll X^{1/2}.$$

I would like a version of this for polynomials.

> Let $f \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$ be non-constant and separable. Then does there exist $\delta > 0$ such that
>   $$\#\{ n \in \mathbb{Z}: |n| \leq X, \, f(n) \text{ is squareful} \} \ll X^{1 - \delta} \quad ?$$

Hopefully there are not some necessary local conditions here that I overlooked. In my application I am happy to change $f$ as required so that one can assume that $f$ is sufficiently "general". Moreover, I can even assume that $f$ is of very large degree if necessary to simplify things.

I would normally try to prove something like this using the large sieve, however the large sieve gives the poor upper bound $X/(\log X)$, whereas I would like a power saving.

If necessary, I'm happy to assume some standard conjectures (e.g. the abc conjecture).

Comment: I think the one necessary condition should be that the polynomial itself (over $\mathbb{C}$) should not be squareful. Apart from the constants you have to exclude the trivial examples such as $f(x) = x^2 (x+1)^3$.

Comment: Yes good point thanks. I added the assumption that $f$ is separable.

Comment: Won't the large sieve give something like $X^{3/4+\epsilon}$ by just arguing with moduli of the form $p^2$?  For most primes $p$, it seems like $n$ would have to live in a bounded number of residue classes $\pmod {p^2}$ and then the exponential sums at $a/p^2$ for $(a,p)=1$ must be big ... .

Comment: @Lucia:The problem is as follows.(though if you are able to fix this I would be very interested). Suppose we are using the large sieve to count the number of squareful integers $n$ and sieving modulo $p^2$ as you suggest. Note that units modulo $p^2$ are squareful. So we are only excluding the $p-1$ residue classes given by $p,\ldots,(p-1)p$. The local $p$-adic density of squareful numbers is then roughly given by $(p^2 - (p - 1))/p^2 = 1 - 1/p + 1/p^2$, which decays like $1/(\log X)$, as claimed.

Comment: Miscalculation on my part, sorry!

Comment: @DanielLoughran: for the density of squarefuls, do you mean $\gg X^{1/2}$, or $\ll X^{5/6}$?

Comment: There are $cX^{1/2}$ squareful integers of absolute value up to $X$, for some $c>0$. This is very easy to prove; see e.g.  Powerful Numbers
S. W. Golomb
The American Mathematical Monthly
Vol. 77, No. 8 (Oct., 1970), pp. 848-852

Comment: Thank you. I think I get confused by the "<<" notation, which I must have learnt as "much less than" a long time ago.

Comment: This $\ll$ is Vinogradov notation, which is standard in analytic number theory.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $f$ is squarefree and of degree at least three, then
the abc conjecture implies $f(x)$ is squareful finite number
of times. For [reference](http://www.math.unicaen.fr/~nitaj/abc.html#Consequences) and several papers of Granville:

> Power free-values of polynomials. Langevin noted in [Lan2] the following conjecture which is a consequence of the abc conjecture.
>   Let $F(X)$ be a polynomial with integer coefficients and no repeated roots. For any $\epsilon > 0$, there exists a constant $C_{\epsilon,F}$ such that for any integer $n$,$|n|^{\deg(F)-1-\epsilon} < C_{\epsilon,F} rad(F(n))$.

Actually abc implies the squareful part of $f(x)$ can't be too large
infinitely often. If the squareful part of $f(x)$ is $s$, then
$ s < C_\epsilon x^{2+\epsilon}$.

Comment: I don't quite follow. Could you provide more details how the conjecture of Langevin helps with my question? Are you also able to give precise references for the claims at the beginning and the end of your answer?

Comment: @DanielLoughran $rad$ is the radical, the product of the distinct prime factors. The radical in the RHS is at most $|n|^{\deg(F)/2}$. The LHS is $|n|^{\deg(F)-1-\epsilon}$. If $\deg(F)>2$ the inequality doesn't hold, contradicting abc.

Comment: @DanielLoughran Here is selfcontained proof. Fix $n>2$, let $F(x)=x^n+1$. Assume $F(X)$ is squareful $F(X)=u^2v^3$. Take the abc triple $a=X^n,b=1,C=X^n+1=u^2v^3$. $rad(abc)=xuv=O(X^{n/2+1})$ while $c \sim X^n$.

Answer (score 4):

In the sieve book of Cojocaru and Murty they give a simple application of the square sieve of Heath-Brown, namely in Theorem 2.3.5 of their book they prove that $$\#\{1\leq n \leq x:f(n)=\square\}\ll_{f,\epsilon} x^{1-\epsilon}$$ for all $0<\epsilon<\frac{1}{3}$. Squares and squarefulls have the same asymptotic density and there is definitely a chance to make the square-sieve approach work for $$\#\{1\leq n \leq x:f(n)=\text{ squarefull}\}$$ without abc. Note that if $f(n)$ is square-full then $f(n)=a^2b^3$ hence there exists $b \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $f(n)b$ is a square. The case $b=1$ is what they do however their proof can be easily adopted to work for $bf(n)$. It gives a bound independent of $b$ by changing $\mathcal{P}$ in their proof to be the set of all primes in $(x^{1/3},2x^{1/3}]\setminus \{p \text{ prime } : p|b\}$. The prime divisors of $b$ that are excluded are at most $\log b\ll \log x$, while the set of primes is $\asymp x^{1/3} (\log x)^{-1}$, therefore all estimates go through unaltered. This does not solve your problem since one has to do something extra to get more saving when $b$ gets larger, but there is some hope.

Comment: Sieving for squares is a much easier problem than sieving for squarefuls. All the sieves I have tried don't seem to work for squarefuls. If you are able to make your argument work I would be very interested, but you have somehow only dealt with the "easy" case when $b$ is small.

Comment: I thought a bit more: One can try the square sieve approach for the set $\{bf(n):1\leq n \leq x, b^3|f(n), b\leq Y\}$. Then as long as $Y\leq x^{1-\epsilon}$ the square sieve works as in their book. This covers your question for the special case $\deg(f)=2$.

Comment: That's nice, but the interesting case is when $\deg(f) > 2$; here one expects $f(n)$ to be squareful only finitely many times.

Comment: Hmm, I now think it is not as easy as I previously thought. I will return if I have more news.